# Extracting data from JSON in Perl

Tags: perl

The following is a sample of my 60MB JSON file:

```
[
   {
      "phish_id":"3332444",
      "url":"http://shydroservice.ru/plugins/content/fboxbot/standardbank3/inet.php",
      "phish_detail_url":"http://www.phishtank.com/phish_detail.php?phish_id=3332444",
      "submission_time":"2015-07-17T09:58:13+00:00",
      "verified":"yes",
      "verification_time":"2015-07-17T10:14:15+00:00",
      "online":"yes",
      "details":[
         {
            "ip_address":"37.140.192.240",
            "cidr_block":"37.140.192.0/24",
            "announcing_network":"197695",
            "rir":"ripencc",
            "country":"RU",
            "detail_time":"2015-07-17T09:59:28+00:00"
         }
      ],
      "target":"Other"
   },
   ...
]
```

I would like get the `ip_address` of `details`, but my code doesn't find `details` array :'(

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use LWP::Simple qw(get);
use JSON qw(decode_json);

my $url = "http://127.0.0.1/test.json";

my $decoded = decode_json(get($url));

foreach my $f ( @decoded ) {
  print $f->{"details"} . "\n";
}
```

I have this message:

```
Not a HASH reference at ./get_article.pl line 15.
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: try `foreach my $f ( @$decoded ) {`

Comment: The program you gave does not give the output you claim it does; it gives a strict error.

Comment: and I think it's better to use JSON::XS module in case of huge data

Comment: You are pulling our leg. The code you posted do not even compile:
`Global symbol "@decoded" requires explicit package name at - line 10.
Execution of - aborted due to compilation errors.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the top level, you have `[]`, so `$decoded` is reference to an array.

```
for my $f (@$decoded) {
   ...
}
```

Inside you have `{}`, so `$f` is a reference to a hash.

```
   my $details = $f->{details};
```

Inside you have `[]`, so `$details` is a reference to an array.

```
   for my $detail (@$details) {
      ...
   }
```

Inside you have `{}`, so `$detail` is a reference to a hash.

```
      my $ip_address = $detail->{ip_address};
```

All together:

```
for my $f (@$decoded) {
   my $details = $f->{details};
   for my $detail (@$details) {
      my $ip_address = $detail->{ip_address};
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! you solved my problem :)
one array in an array ... so easy when anybody says the solution.